# I have a prolem with feast[redis]

Tags: redis, mlops, feast

I am installing some packages for environment and I followed the steps:

1. I clone this repo: https://github.com/MLOpsVN/mlops-crash-course-code
2. `pip install -r dev_requirements.txt` (in folder mlops-crash-course-code/pipeline_data)

But when I install feast[redis]==0.24.0. I got the following error:

```
(venv) C:\MLOpsVN\mlops-crash-course-code\data_pipeline>pip install feast[redis]==0.23.2
Collecting feast==0.23.2 (from feast[redis]==0.23.2)
  Using cached feast-0.23.2.tar.gz (3.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in feast setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dictionary whose values are strings or lists of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried changing the version of python from 3.9 to 3.10 but it didn't work.

Comment: Update new version `py -m pip install feast` Released: Feb 17, 2024

Answer (score 0):

Update new version Released: Feb 17, 2024.

```
py -m pip install feast
```